# SOC1 Abend in Cobol program

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have a SOC1 abend when executing mt cobol program. Any ideas?[image]

I get these messages in the JESMSGLG

10.18.45 JOB07120  IGD17296I DYNAMIC VOLUME COUNT (DVC=5) WAS USED TO  433
   433             EXTEND DATA SET VALSD.ALT.CACD602.RF0020RC.LONENSEL.#C
10.18.48 JOB07120  IGD17296I DYNAMIC VOLUME COUNT (DVC=5) WAS USED TO  467
   467             EXTEND DATA SET VALSD.ALT.CACD602.RF0020RC.LONENSEL.#C
10.18.51 JOB07120  IGD17296I DYNAMIC VOLUME COUNT (DVC=5) WAS USED TO  544
   544             EXTEND DATA SET VALSD.ALT.CACD602.RF0020RC.LONENSEL.#C
10.18.54 JOB07120  IGD17296I DYNAMIC VOLUME COUNT (DVC=5) WAS USED TO  597
   597             EXTEND DATA SET VALSD.ALT.CACD602.RF0020RC.LONENSEL.#C
10.18.59 JOB07120  IEC028I 837-08,IFG0554A,OCACD602,COLST51P,LONENSEL,6355,TSOD05,  688
   688             VALSD.ALT.CACD602.RF0020RC.LONENSEL.#C

EDIT: When I use less input (= less output) I don't get the abend.

Comment: Yeah, it's a program error. Please don't use screenprints, but copy/paste from your emulator. If there's anything to look up, I'm, for one, not going to retype it because you can't be bothered to make it easy for people. It is a S0C1, not a SOC1. You seem to be sitting there in the debugger, so I'm guessing you already know which line it is one. You need to show the code around where it failed, and the relevant definitions of data used where it failed.

Comment: A S0C1 is an Operation Exception. Your program has tried to execute an instruction which does not exist. Is your program "statically bound"? Check the binder/linkedit map for error (non-RC=0) and understand those, if any. Otherwise the S0C1 comes from something overwriting your executable code. or if it happens to be in an Assembler program, or... so you need to describe more.

Comment: Hah! Are you trying to open a file? Does the DDname (the external name of your file) exist in the JCL? You have any messages in file one or three of the spool output?

Comment: Messages added in original post

Comment: From the IEC028I message you got an S837 abend.You are correct that it is an issue with the number of records being written and the space they occupy. Basically you ran out of volumes. Since IGD17296I implies that five volumes were used before the failure, it looks like you are only using one, and your data does not fit. How much output are you expecting? Check with your colleagues whether you should be specifying anything additional for large data sets, if they don't know, contact your storage technicians. Ask technical support to explain why the S837 allowed the step to continue, giving S0C1

Comment: A good estimate of how large the output should be is necessary. There's no point in allocating more storage if a program is erroneously writing output in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from the image, but like the guys before stated, disk space appears to be your problem.  Try to allocate a small size on the primary allocation, and more on secondary.  My recollection of this problem is that the primary allocation needs one chunk of space of specified size, but secondary allocations are split.  This becomes more important when disc space is limited.  Try running an `idcams listcat` to check for space.  Then if necessary include a `vol=ser` parameter into your JCL. It might also be a good idea to include some file status checking into Cobol program.  This makes issues like this far easier to resolve.